# Do I need the license update package for Juniper SRX100

Tags: licensing, juniper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I need a router/firewall to connect a couple of colocated servers to the internet.

I was looking at the Juniper SRX100 but a friend told me I would need to buy the 3 year license update package (which costs about $700) to keep its operating system updated.

Is this true? do I need to buy a licence package along with the SRX100 to operate it reliably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://kb.juniper.net/KB15395